# MongoDb unable to populate user

Tags: database, mongodb

Hi I am trying to populate user into another schema called feedbackschema.

Feedback schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const {
  Schema,
} = mongoose;

// Create Schema
const FeedbackSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users',
  },
  pro: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  con: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  comments: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  rating: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

// Create model
const feedback = mongoose.model('feedbacks', FeedbackSchema);

module.exports = feedback;
```

User Schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const {
  Schema,
} = mongoose;

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false,
  },
});

// Create a model
const user = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

// Export the model
module.exports = user;
```

and here is my controller where I am trying to populate the user

```js
getAllFeedbacks: async (req, res) => {
    const errors = {};
    try {
      const feedbacks = await Feedback.find().populate('user');
      return res.json(feedbacks);
    } catch (err) {
      errors.noFeedbacks = 'Please try again';
      return res.status(404).json(errors);
    }
  },
```

Json I am receiving through postman is this

```js
[
    {
        "_id": "5b3adf88f3c4cd836bdc2eda",
        "pro": "knfklngfdklgnfdgknkln",
        "con": "Sales executive updates",
        "comments": "This is a another funfact for me is me too",
        "rating": "8",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

It is supposed to show user key but somehow its not working. I checked the current user data is already there but for some reason its not pushing the user info feedback object.

**FeedBack collection**

```
 [
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5b3adf88f3c4cd836bdc2eda"
    },
    "pro": "knfklngfdklgnfdgknkln",
    "con": "Sales executive updates",
    "comments": "This is a another funfact for me is me too",
    "rating": "8",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

**User Collection**

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5b37e456565971258da97d5e"
    },
    "isAdmin": false,
    "name": "montygoldy",
    "email": "montygoldy@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$zWbxV0Q3VPUxRC6lzJyPBec3P/8zYBaSCTJ2n88Uru3zzFlicR2rq",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you please show your sample collection copying from mongo shell or robomongo

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet updated the post

Comment: I need you sample collections... Please copy it from mlab and paste it here... Please don't paste screen shots

Comment: Feedback collection {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b3adf88f3c4cd836bdc2eda"
    },
    "pro": "knfklngfdklgnfdgknkln",
    "con": "Sales executive updates",
    "comments": "This is a another funfact for me is me too",
    "rating": "8",
    "__v": 0
}

Comment: user collection{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b37e456565971258da97d5e"
    },
    "isAdmin": false,
    "name": "montygoldy",
    "email": "montygoldy@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$zWbxV0Q3VPUxRC6lzJyPBec3P/8zYBaSCTJ2n88Uru3zzFlicR2rq",
    "__v": 0
}

Comment: where is users `_id` in the FeedBack collection? I cannot see user `_id` in the feedback so how can you populate!!!

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet yes thats the problem hw should i fix it. Am i doing anything wrong in the model

Comment: You cannot do this using populate... You need to do this using `$lookup` aggregation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174293/discussion-between-montygoldy-and-anthony-winzlet).

Comment: you can use the below answer... It will work for you